# Regex to extract all digits after last occurrence of a special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract all digits after last occurrence of character "-" so for example 311-1974-8 should return me 8 and 311-1974-348 should return 348

edit:

Added clarification from a comment:

actually it's an external tool which provides it's own inbuild functionalists and i have no other option but to use regex to extract this. No JS can be applied :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment it's for an external tool so...

`-([0-9]+)$`

dunno how your tool handles captured groups or anything...

Comment: your solution give me 4 for input 311-8 while i need 8 to be returned

Comment: It works if you're able to fetch `str.match(/-([0-9]+)$/)[1]`. This question doesn't make sense until you precise **how** the regex will be used !

Comment: my solution would not have matched "311-8" you are doing it wrong then.

Answer (score 3):

This captures the last number.

```
var str = '311-1974-348';
var matches = str.match(/-(\d+)$/);
var match = matches ? matches[1] : null;
console.log("matched? " + match);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try matching on `/[^-]+$/`, e.g.:

```
var s = '311-1974-348';
s.match(/[^-]+$/); // => ["348"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply spliting ?

```
var str = input.split('-').pop();
```

Comment: actually it's an external tool which provides it's own inbuild functionalists and i have no other option but to use regex to extract this. No JS can be applied :(

Comment: And what regex function will you call ?

Comment: @dystroy  many tools offer regex matching..think analytics tools or tag management systems that make rules based on matches

Comment: I tried -(?:.(?!-))+$ so far which five me last index of "-" but that doesn't solve my purpose, i need to slice down the last digit after last occurrence of "-"

Comment: @CrayonViolent Yes but it's not the same if you can call match with the index in the resulting array or not. This question is much too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `/[0-9]+$/`.  It worked on both the inputs you provided.